# Write HTML within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Can anyone help me to convert this to proper JavaScript?

```
<script>var datePostForAll = &#39;<div class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></div>&#39;;</script>
```

Thank you!
:*

Comment: I've tagged this as Blogger, because you're using custom Blogger markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is proper JavaScript. It's the same as writing:

```
<script>
   var datePostForAll = "<div class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></div>";
</script>
```

They're used `&#39;` instead of an apostrophe so they don't have to escape `'` and `"` marks inside the string. The `<data:post.dateHeader/>` is custom Blogger markup and will be evaluated when it is run. Because the contents of `<data:post.dateHeader/>` may include quote marks, they chose to wrap the string in `&#39;` to prevent accidentally introducing unescaped elements into the string. Regardless, as this will be outputting a date, wrapping it in quotes should be fine.

Comment: Except what is `<data:post.dateHeader/>` supposed to be?

Comment: @BenLee That is a custom blogger tag and will be parsed by the blogger engine. in fact... time to edit

Comment: HEY!!! Thanks! It worked and now I have Date Posts in all my blogspot posts!!! Thanks BEN!!!!!!!!! It was very simple hehehe but I never thought in using the "" instead of &#39;             THANKS AGAIN AND BIG KISS FROM PORTUGAL´

Comment: Can I use: <script>document.write(<div class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></div>);</script>??????

Comment: You could try `<script>document.write("<div class='date-header'><data:post.dateHeader/></div>");</script>`... notice the `"` :)

Comment: I tried but the blogguer strips out the <data:post.dateHeader/>... I think it is because the variable should be before the real first value to after write it again... Anyway just wanted to short the code one line. Thanks again! :*